# Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php55"

Tags: php, bash, terminal, homebrew, zsh

Whenever I open a new terminal shell in macOS 10.12.6, there's a long pause and I get the following message:

`Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php55"`

I think this started happening when I upgraded my system php to 7.1.19. It is installed to /usr/local/bin/php. I removed all other brew taps related to PHP. There are no `brew doctor` related issues about php either.

I've checked my `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.zshrc` and `aliases.zsh` files for anything that might be referencing PHP, but I've found nothing.

I'm not sure where this error is coming from or how to remove it.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Please try to remove all php packages that you have `brew remove php5`, `brew remove php7`, or something like that, and later install it again. I had an issue with php versions some time ago, and solution more or less like that helped me.

Comment: Okay, I tried removing everything related to PHP from brew, and I reinstalled php 7.2, but no change. The error continues to appear. I also had a php-mcrypt in there, which removed, and I upgraded httpd. No luck.

Comment: Does `brew doctor` find anything?

Comment: Just a warning for unlinked kegs: python@2 and node. Nothing else.